# Application.StartupPath in Xamarin

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am looking for help to convert following winForm code to work in Xamarin Android.
Could not figure out what is the equivalent of Application.StartupPath in Xamarin.

```
private GoogleCredential CreateCredential()

{
        // the place to enter google API key (= json file).
        using (var stream = new FileStream(Application.StartupPath + "\\key-here.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) //error on this line
        {
            string[] scopes = { VisionService.Scope.CloudPlatform };
            var credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream);
            credential = credential.CreateScoped(scopes);
            return credential;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really a concept of a starting directory when running the app. The files that are distributed with the app, are in the assembly. You'll have to include it as an `Embedded Resource` and load it as a stream.

You can read up on it here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/files/#Loading_Files_Embedded_as_Resources

Comment: the link was helpful. Thank you.